# How to pass a long string(with new lines) variable as enviroment to ssh command

Tags: linux, shell

```
KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
ssh root@127.0.0.1 KEY="$KEY" echo "hi"
```

It will fail and display error like this:

```
bash: AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDJ65FHdb8FyD...tpFnRUSZ: No such file or directory
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: You forgot to quote `$KEY`.

Comment: add quote to $KEY is the same to get this error

Comment: Since the command is run on the remote server, you must make sure that it is properly quoted there too ... Something like `KEY="'$KEY'"`, combining double and single quotes.

Comment: thank u much! It works! It's so tricky...... what's the difference between: a="'abc'" b='abc' c=abc?

Comment: Double quotes interpolate variables. Single quotes don't. No quotes just split on spaces. It was the latter that caused the error. You could also have nested in your special case double quotes inside double quotes, but then the inner ones would need escaping, which is awkward to type. That's why I put the single quotes inside. You need the double quotes outside, in order to have `$KEY` interpolated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bash is used:

For the more generic case, where the input may contain arbitrary characters, including quotes, consider using the (bas specific) `${var@A}` to create an assignment:

```
ssh root@localhost ${KEY@A} echo 'hi'
```

Update 1: bash (version 4.4) man page: on the '@A' (and other) operation:

> ```
>   ${parameter@operator}
>           Parameter  transformation.   The  expansion  is either a transformation of the value of parameter or information
>           about parameter itself, depending on the value of operator.  Each operator is a single letter:
>
>           Q      The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input.
>           E      The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter with backslash escape sequences expanded as with
>                  the $'...' quoting mechansim.
>           P      The  expansion  is a string that is the result of expanding the value of parameter as if it were a prompt
>                  string (see PROMPTING below).
>           A      The expansion is a string in the form of an assignment statement or declare command that,  if  evaluated,
>                  will recreate parameter with its attributes and value.
>           a      The expansion is a string consisting of flag values representing parameter's attributes.
> ```

Comment: May I ask for the reference of such thing like ${var@A}? I am a little bit confused. Thanks!

Comment: I did read the man bash, there is no ${var@A} but only ${name@}. What is A for?

Comment: @DC it might be hard to find. search for 'paramter@operator'. In my version of 'man bash', just after the section on ',,', and '^^'. I'll post the text to the answer

Comment: I upgraded bash then I found it in man bash. However, it doesn't work: KEY=$(< ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) && echo "${KEY@A}"   The error is: bash: ${KEY@A}: bad substitution

Comment: Not sure why not working for you. Can you verify you  are using the updated version `set | grep -i bash` ?